# Why does my meals info not show in my project after I append data to table?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have created an order food project that has a `Meal` model and cms controller and a webcms web controller and I created an `Index` view from webcms. I want to show all meals info in it as a table using Ajax but it only show the headers of the table. I tried to get data using httpget in function and it worked fine.

My webcms controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using Delivary.Models;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Delivary.Controllers.api
{
    public class webcmsController : ApiController
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db;

        public webcmsController()
        {
            db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Meal> GetMeals()
        {
            return db.MealTable;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public Meal GetoneMeal( int id)
        {
            var c = db.MealTable.SingleOrDefault(x => x.MealId == id);
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

My `Meal` model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Delivary.Models
{
    public class Meal
    {
        public int MealId { get; set; }
        public string MealName { get; set; }
        public double MealPrice { get; set; }
        public string MealImg { get; set; }
        public string Cat { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My cms controller index view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<center>
    <br />
    <table id="meals_tbl" class="table table-bordered ">
        <tr>
            <th>MealId</th>
            <th>MealName</th>
            <th>MealPrice</th>
            <th>MealImg</th>
            <th>Cat</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        function showMeals() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/webcms",
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                        var res = '<tr>';
                        res += '<td>' + v.MealId + '</td>';
                        res += '<td>' + v.MealName + '</td>';
                        res += '<td>' + v.MealPrice + '</td>';
                        res += '<td>' + v.MealImg + '</td>';
                        res += '<td>' + v.Cat + '</td>';
                        res += '<td> Edit/td>';
                        res += '<td> Delete/td>';

                        res += '</tr>';
                       
                        $("#meals_tbl").append(res);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            showMeals();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: You have missing the method name in your ajax code like url: "/api/webcms/GetMeals", try with method name if your method are working perfectly then you get the data and working properly your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax code update the URL with method name i.e.

```
$.ajax({
          url: "/webcms/GetMeals",

          ...
        });
```

Comment: thank you,but it didn't work

Comment: Try using without API. I have edit my answer. Also check the url in browser directly to see if it is hitting the designated action. Another possibility is that your controller action is API and you are trying normal ajax call not an API ajax call. Either change controller to normal controller or use api call with ajax code.

Comment: i but a break point in getmeals function but it didn't reach it

Comment: This means that your ajax method or action call is not working with ApI controller. You need to make api call using ajax jQuery only then your target API action will hit.